# how to place text along MapLineSeries in amCharts

Tags: javascript, amcharts

https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/Egeeay?editors=0010

how can i achieve the text along the line just like in the link above with version 4?

This is my code so far but it does not show the text label

```
function createLine(imagesToConnect) {
        // create line series
        var lineSeries = mapChart.series.push(new am4maps.MapLineSeries());
        var mapLine = lineSeries.mapLines.create();
        // tell the line to connect cities (alternatevely you can also specify latitudes/longitudes)
        mapLine.imagesToConnect = imagesToConnect
        // make it dashed
        mapLine.line.strokeDasharray = "1,1";
        mapLine.line.strokeOpacity = 0.2;

        //create label container
        var labelContainer = mapLine.lineObjects.create();
        //set label
        let label = labelContainer.createChild(am4core.Label)
        label.fill = am4core.color("#eeeab5")
        label.text = "This is a text";
        label.width = 30;
        label.height = 20;
        console.log(mapLine);


        // create plane container
        var planeContainer = mapLine.lineObjects.create();
        planeContainer.position = 0;
        // set svg path of a plane for the sprite
        var plane = planeContainer.createChild(am4core.Sprite);
        planeContainer.nonScaling = false;
        planeContainer.scale = 0.015;

        plane.path = "M71,515.3l-33,72.5c-0.9,2.1,0.6,4.4,2.9,4.4l19.7,0c2.8,0,5.4-1,7.5-2.9l54.1-39.9c2.4-2.2,5.4-3.4,8.6-3.4 l103.9,0c1.8,0,3,1.8,2.3,3.5l-64.5,153.7c-0.7,1.6,0.5,3.3,2.2,3.3l40.5,0c2.9,0,5.7-1.3,7.5-3.6L338.4,554c3.9-5,9.9-8,16.2-8c24.2,0,85.5-0.1,109.1-0.2c21.4-0.1,41-6.3,59-17.8c4.2-2.6,7.9-6.1,11.2-9.8c2.6-2.9,3.8-5.7,3.7-8.5c0.1-2.8-1.1-5.5-3.7-8.5c-3.3-3.7-7-7.2-11.2-9.8c-18-11.5-37.6-17.7-59-17.8c-23.6-0.1-84.9-0.2-109.1-0.2c-6.4,0-12.3-2.9-16.2-8L222.6,316.6c-1.8-2.3-4.5-3.6-7.5-3.6l-40.5,0c-1.7,0-2.9,1.7-2.2,3.3L237,470c0.7,1.7-0.5,3.5-2.3,3.5l-103.9,0c-3.2,0-6.2-1.2-8.6-3.4l-54.1-39.9c-2.1-1.9-4.7-2.9-7.5-2.9l-19.7,0c-2.3,0-3.8,2.4-2.9,4.4l33,72.5C72.6,507.7,72.6,511.8,71,515.3z";
        plane.fill = am4core.color("#eeeab5");
        // make the plane to be bigger in the middle of the line

        plane.horizontalCenter = "middle";
        plane.verticalCenter = "middle";
        planeContainer.adapter.add("scale", function (scale, target) {
            return (0.07 - 0.10 * (Math.abs(0.5 - target.position))) / mapChart.zoomLevel;
        })

        var animation = planeContainer.animate({ property: "position", from: 0, to: 1 }, 3000).delay(300);
    }
```

**Solution**

I solved my problem by simply adding

```
labelContainer.position = 0.5;
```

after the LabelContainer line